# Do I have to use CopyTo to get a custom collection into an enumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

Consider the following code:

```
var results = searcher.FindAll();

SearchResult[] srList = new SearchResult[results.Count];
results.CopyTo(srList, 0);
```

where `searcher.FindAll()` returns a [`System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection.aspx).

**Do I have to use the `CopyTo` to get them into an enumerable that I can then later use in a `Parallel.ForEach`?** *And if so, why?*

I have `using System.Linq` but there isn't a `ToList` method popping up.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`Cast<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) to cast a `SearchResultCollection` to `IEnumerable<T>`, and [`ToArray<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) to create an array.

```
SearchResult[] results = searcher.FindAll().Cast<SearchResult>().ToArray();
```

Make sure you include the System.Linq namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: +1 for correct answer... also it is very surprising Michael did not see it explicitly mentioned on page linked from the question: `Cast<TResult>` Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type. (Defined by Enumerable.)

Comment: @Nuffin: `searcher.FindAll.Cast<SearchResult>()`

Comment: Does anyone know why this works, but trying to cast with `(IEnumerable<SearchResult>)searcher` does not?

Comment: @codeMonkey It's because `SearchResultCollection` implements `IEnumerable` instead of the generic `IEnumerable<SearchResult>` interface, so you have to use the `Cast` extension.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Cast<T>` extension method to go from a non-generic `IEnumerable` to an `IEnumerable<SearchResult>`:

```
var results = searcher.FindAll().Cast<SearchResult>();
```

Comment: huh? isn't that pretty much the answer jrummell already gave?

Comment: The OP asked for an `IEnumerable`, not an `Array`.  That clarification was added to @jrummel's answer after I started my answer.

Comment: awwww k +1 for you too then :p